# sticky attribute not working with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

trying to make a gui for a calculator in tkinter and the sticky attribute is just not working for me

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class MyCal:

    def __init__(self):

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Calculator")

        self.output_frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.output_frame.grid(sticky='nsew')

        self.input_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.input_box = tk.Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.input_var, font=("Corbel", 18))
        self.input_box.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky='nsew')

        self.buttonframe = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.buttonframe.grid(sticky='nsew')

        rows = 6
        cols = 4

        for i in range(rows):
            self.buttonframe.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
        
        for i in range(cols):
            self.buttonframe.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

        button_texts = [
            "%", "CE", "C", "DEL", "1/x", "x^2", "2/x", "/", "7", "8", "9", "X", "4", "5", "6", "-", "1", "2", "3", "+", "+/-", "0", ".", "="
        ]

        for i in range(rows):
            for j in range(cols):
                button_text = button_texts[i * cols + j]
                button = tk.Button(self.buttonframe, text=button_text, font=("Corbel", 18), height=1, width=5)
                button.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky='nsew', padx=1, pady=1)

        self.root.mainloop()
MyCal()
```

Tried changing the values/weight of the columns and asking chatgpt but nothing
any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: your code is running without any error. what are you expecting and what is going wrong?be more clear

Comment: the sticky attribute does not do anything for me when i run the code, resizing the box the pannels stay as they are

Comment: oh okay, I understand you issue, I am posting the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resizing behavior of the grid rows and columns is not set up to distribute the extra space when you expand the window. The sticky attribute will only position and stretch the widgets within their grid cell but if the cells themselves do not expand or contract with the window, the widgets won't either.

To ensure that the grid cells resize with the window, you need to configure the weight property of the rows and columns in your grid. The weight property determines how much a row or column should expand or contract relative to the amount of space available in the grid.

Modify the last few lines of your code like the following, this configuration ensures that the frames expand vertically and horizontally within the main window:

```
        for i in range(rows):
            self.buttonframe.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
            for j in range(cols):
                self.buttonframe.columnconfigure(j, weight=1)
                button_text = button_texts[i * cols + j]
                button = tk.Button(self.buttonframe, text=button_text, font=("Corbel", 18), height=1, width=5)
                button.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky='nsew', padx=1, pady=1)
        
        self.root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)  # For the input box
        self.root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)  # For the button frame
        self.root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: nice to hear that. you are welcome!